# errors with excel workbooks

Tags: c#, excel

I'm having hard time to work with excel workbooks from c#.
i cant get basic operations to work right and for some reason it seems that documentation
about excel related classes is not as good as others.
I've learned to work with xml and text files so far and it was by far more easy then excel.
I've copy the next example from msdn forums but i cant get it to work, even having hard time
to declare the namespace, i get only errors from this code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object oExcel=new Excel.Application();
            object oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Book1.xls");
            object oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(1);
```

Comment: it cant recodnize excel if i declare the namespace as i did

Comment: What if you use `using Microsoft.Office.Interop` only ?

Comment: Also, please provide the exact error message, not your interpretation.

Comment: [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/c9e83756-4ae2-4ed4-b154-1537f3bb3a22/) might help.

Comment: are you familiar with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: that gives me"the type or namespace in excel cannot be found"

Comment: you need to add the using as well as right click reference and look for Microsoft.Office do you have the Microsoft Office Tools installed ..?

Comment: DJ KRAZE i'm not, i'm exploring it now but like i said it seems much harder then other issue's like xml and txt files, the documentation on this subject is not as good as its in the subjects i mentioned

Comment: DK KRAZE i added a refrence in COM library ofc to excel object 14 and i have microsoft office tools

Comment: please show the full code in regards to where the code is hanging and or throwing an Error

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    Excel.ApplicationClass _Excel;
    Excel.Workbook WB;
    Excel.Worksheet WS;

try
    {

    _Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
    WB = _Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Book1.xls",
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        //do something
        WB.Visible = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WB.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(WB);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_Excel);
    }
```

Option 2 that you could try as well..
Here is a Link as well follow the steps in the screen shot provided in this link
[How to Open an Excel File in C#](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-open-excel.htm)

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp ;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("csharp.net-informations.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            MessageBox.Show(xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1","A1").Value2.ToString());

            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Here is an Article / another way to read or open an Excel file
[Excel Interop with .NET](http://dontbreakthebuild.com/2011/01/30/excel-and-c-interop-with-net-4-how-to-read-data-from-excel/)

Comment: i get an error with "Excel.ApplicationClass" -inteop type cannot be embedded, use the applicable interface instead.

Comment: i have to use "using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" but i still get the former error, thanks for the link.

Comment: Please show the full bit of code for the block that you posted. also state what version of Microsoft Office you are running... if you are using Office 2007 don't import Interop version 11.0 its like version 12 and above..